Access CodeArtifact from inside an EC2 instance
0
I'm experimenting with AWS Services to build my project, a backend Java using Docker for containers and Maven for dependencies, and Angular 16 for my front end, right now I have a VPC with 6 subnets, two of them are public. I have an RDS instance with public access as well and a Free Tier EC2 instance running with connection to this RDS instance, didn't test this connection yet so not sure if it works. I'm trying to build my project inside the EC2, a Docker Compose Up command with multiple Java Maven services where two of them have a dependency from my CodeArtifact repository but, not only it can't access this dependency, even though I have the settings.xml configured correctly, the command to get CodeArtifact's token ends with a time out when I try to run it inside the EC2, but works fine on my local machine. My Security Groups, the ones that this EC2 is using, have outbound permission to all protocols on "0.0.0.0/0" and "::/0" and my CodeArtifact policies are allowing everything to my root user and my dev user, which I'm using right now Am I doing something wrong? I saw here that it is possible but maybe not anymore? The public subnets have the same ACL configuration, tried to add another rule to allow outbound and inbound traffic but didn't work!

I'm also adding the inbound and outbound rules here to make sure I'm not forgetting some configuration

Tried to create an IAM Role but also didn't work! I created a new instance and tried both with and without the IAM Role, even after attaching the IAM Role I'm getting timed out! I managed to take a screenshot with both before and after I attached the IAM Role


Solved the problem by assigning an IPv4 to my EC2 instance! Don't really know if that's what caused it but honestly, this is the only different thing I did this time and it worked now! Thank you guys and if I did or assumed something wrong, please correct me!
